# Check if `do_action()` in WordPress returns any result

Tags: hooks, actions

I want to check if `do_action('some_hook')` in WordPress returns/echoes any result for a specific post. I've tried using `has_action('some_hook')` but it only checks if `'some_hook'` has any registered handler at global level, it does not check if a specific post has any result for that hook. Can anybody please tell me how to achieve what I want?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? actions (in contrast to filters) should not have any result (read: ouput/return/..)

Comment: `do_action()` does echo the result, provided some some function is hooked into it via `add_action()`. I'm not sure I understand what you meant?

Comment: You're right, I was thinking in the wrong direction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible way could be to use PHP's output buffering via [`ob_start()`](https://secure.php.net/ob_start) like so

```
ob_start();
do_action('my_hook');

$content = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

if (empty($content)) {
    // no output generated
} else {
    // had some output
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I actually tried this method before but it was not working. it works now!